# PicoCMS Pagination for Blog

Tags: php, css, html, pagination

I set up PicoCMS on my site and I have everything set up and working except for the blog pages. The "Older Posts" button isn't working, and I couldn't find anywhere on the theme documentation or Pagination of how to set this up. This is the theme URL https://github.com/BesrourMS/clean-blog and this is the URL for Pagination https://github.com/rewdy/Pico-Pagination

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the issue was located in the Pagination plugin. My website's home page is static and the blog is located at /blog. You must change `'page_indicator' => 'blog',` instead of `'page_indicator' => 'page',`